# Ruby file won't load for me

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, irb

I'm taking a coding class and ran into a problem while trying to code along with the instructor. I am trying to learn the part about mixins and the Enumerable module, and made this file, just like the instructor did, but it's not working for me. I have Ruby installed and have been successfully using RVM to manage Ruby and Rails versions so far, so I don't understand why this isn't working for me. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the screencaps of the errors I get in my terminal:

[image]

[image]

And here is my sample code:

```
     # Enumerable as a mixin

     class ToToList
       include 'Enumerable'

       attr_accessor :items, :finished_items

       def initialize
         @items = []
       end

       def each
         items.each {|item| yield item}
       end
     end

     # list = ToToList.new
     # list.items = ['laundry', 'dishes', 'vacuum']
     # list.items.select {|i| i.length > 6}
```

Comment: Those error messages are a bit hard to read.  Can you take screen-caps without the translucent terminal?  Or better yet, copy-paste the error message?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. Apparently, in newer versions of Ruby (I am currently using Ruby v. 2.1.2 p95), the single quotes around Enumerable in the `include` statement is what made it not work correctly. After conferring with the manual at [ruby-docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Enumerable.html), I saw this code sample: `include Enumerable` and noticed that there were no single quotes around it. So I removed the single quotes and it now works fine.

Comment: In what version of Ruby does single quotes around 'Enumerable' work?

Comment: I don't know. The version wasn't specified in the lynda.com video tutorial I was trying to do (titled "Ruby Essentials") that is more than a year old,so...

Answer (score 0):

`require` will look for a file called `to_do_list.rb` on your `$LOAD_PATH`.  Chances are if you've got some git repo and that's your working directory for your project, it won't be on your `$LOAD_PATH`.  Usually `$LOAD_PATH` mostly has just standard library stuff.

You can either use `require` passing it the full (absolute) path to your `to_do_list.rb` file, or use `require_relative` and pass it the path to said file relative to your current location (wherever you invoked `irb` from).

Comment: I tried that Amit, and it's still not working for me.

Comment: I tried using require and passing the absolute path and also tried it the other way, using require_relative. Neither works for me.

Comment: If you use `require` and pass it the correct absolute path, it should load the file.  Are you seeing the same error message?

Comment: No. I now get a TypeError: wrong argument type String (expected Module) error. Underneath that one in the error stack, I get another error saying NoMethodError: undefined method 'ruby' for Main:Object.

Comment: Okay, so that solved your original problem, you now have an entirely new one.  You might encounter a series of different problems until you've fully debugged your code, you should post separate questions for separate problems.